# Taking text from a file and formatting it

Tags: python, performance, csv, formatting

My code takes numbers from a large text file, then splits it to organise the spacing and to place it into a 2-dimensional array. The code is used to get data for a job scheduler that I'm building.

```
#reading in workload data
def getworkload():
    work = []
    strings = []
    with open("workload.txt") as f:
        read_data = f.read()
        jobs = read_data.split("\n")
    for j in jobs:
        strings.append(" ".join(j.split()))
    for i in strings:
        work.append([float(s) for s in i.split(" ")])
    return work

print(getworkload())
```

The [text file](https://www.writeurl.com/publish/0nyoo3ntnueidy248o1s) is over 2000 lines long, and looks like this:

```
    1        0 1835117 330855  640   5886   945   -1     -1    -1  5   2   1   4  9 -1 -1 -1
    2        0 2265800 251924  640   3124   945   -1     -1    -1  5   2   1   4  9 -1 -1 -1
    3        1 3114175     -1  640     -1   945   -1     -1    -1  5   2   1   4  9 -1 -1 -1
    4  1813487   7481     -1  128     -1 20250   -1     -1    -1  5   3   1   5  8 -1 -1 -1
    5  1814044      0    122  512   1.13  1181   -1     -1    -1  1   1   1   1  9 -1 -1 -1
    6  1814374      1     51  512     -1  1181   -1     -1    -1  1   1   1   2  9 -1 -1 -1
    7  1814511      0     55  512     -1  1181   -1     -1    -1  1   1   1   2  9 -1 -1 -1
    8  1814695      1     51  512     -1  1181   -1     -1    -1  1   1   1   2  9 -1 -1 -1
    9  1815198      0     75  512   2.14  1181   -1     -1    -1  1   1   1   2  9 -1 -1 -1
   10  1815617      0    115  512   1.87  1181   -1     -1    -1  1   1   1   1  9 -1 -1 -1
    …
```

It takes 2 and a half minutes to run but I can print the returned data. How can it be optimised?

Comment: Welcome on Code Review. I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. If you're having trouble getting something working, or ask for features, then you'd better ask on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (the main site)

Comment: The code works, as I can print work_row with out any problems and I know that work will be a two dimensional array/list. I just believe it can be sped up.

Comment: "If I try to print work the text is too long and I get an overflow error" for me it's sounds lile you have a problem. Try to reformulated your question to get rid of this doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a lot of unnecessary work. Why split each row only to join it with single spaces and then split it again by those single spaces?

Instead, here is a list comprehension that should do the same thing:

```
def get_workload(file_name="workload.txt"):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        return [[float(x) for x in row.split()] for row in f]
```

This uses the fact that files are iterable and when iterating over them you get each row on its own.

If this is still too slow (or e.g. too large to fit into memory), then you need to process each row separately. For this you would make this a generator of processed lines:

```
def get_workload(file_name="workload.txt"):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for row in f:
            yield [float(x) for x in row.split()]
```